# VSCode debug cpp ROS node

Tags: c++, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to debug my cpp ROS node, based on the microepsilon_scancontrol (I am porting it to the latest driver).
I can build with catkin, I can start it, but ofc not perfect (why would it..).

Therefor, I would like to debug it. I am using:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- VSCode + cpp extension (Microsoft)
- ROS kinetic
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ajshort.ros

When I start debug I select ROS debugger and run my code with roslaunch (or rosrun, doesn't matter... same result). My node starts in the built-in console, but basically that's it, nothing more. Even if I add some brakepoints, doesn't matter, won't stop, keep running.

What am I missing?
Also this automatic include generator doesn't seem to work. glibconfig.h is missing for some reason (I can build my code with catkin_make, so it has to be somewhere). And to be honest it is not really generating all of the includes, vscode offers me to add this and that, but when it comes to glibconfig.h it stops and ask me to add it manually.

Do you guys have some advice how to debug nodes in the given environment?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313371/vscode-debug-cpp-ros-node/) by [balint.tahi](https://answers.ros.org/users/39271/balint.tahi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2019-01-22

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Isha Dijcks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38758/isha-dijcks/) on 2019-01-22**:\

> run my code with roslaunch (or rosrun, doesn't matter... same result).

Do you mean you type roslaunch/rosrun in the built-in terminal?

**Comment by [balint.tahi](https://answers.ros.org/users/39271/balint.tahi/) on 2019-01-22**:
ofc not. debug screen -> play button (or pressing F5), then I select ROS -> roslaunch (or rosrun) -> my package -> launch file. and then it starts a new console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe [this](https://github.com/ms-iot/vscode-ros/blob/master/doc/debug-support.md#launch) is exactly what you're looking for.

I know this is a relatively old post, but I recently came across this page still feeling lost. I then found the above doc on the [vscode-ros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-iot.vscode-ros) github, and it literally walks you through how to debug a node even when launching from a *.launch file. I do believe it is important to build your catkin workspace using the following line like it says in the notes.

```
$ catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
```

---

Originally posted by [stephanst](https://answers.ros.org/users/56098/stephanst/) with karma: 136 on 2020-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [curiousgeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/87285/curiousgeorge/) on 2021-10-14**:
created an account just to thank you. this did it for me

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same issue where my simple c++ code projects built with ***cmake*** works perfectly fine but not the same c++ file in catkin workspace which uses **catkin_make**. I had the executable run with out the errors but doesn't stop at my break points to debug my code. Later with the following changes in the **launch.json** and **tasks.json**, I could debug my executables(the ones I run using roslaunch or rosrun from terminal) in vscode effortlessly.

Please note to use the below fields correctly in respective json files as those commands are the ones that helps to pipe and enable the code with debugger in vscode and terminal.

****In launch.json--****

1. "preLaunchTask": "prerun"
2. "avoidWindowsConsoleRedirection": true
3. "stopAtEntry": false

**In tasks.json --**

1. ***in Prerun task***
   a. "command": "source ./devel/setup.bash && export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311/ "
2. *In build task*
   a. "command": "catkin config --extend /opt/ros/kinetic && catkin build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = Debug -j8"

The above changes would hopefully work for anyone struggling with a similar issue. The changes are considered to work assuming the ROS environment is setup with the required extensions and catkin_make is executed without any errors.

---

**********************************************  **launch.json**   *************************************************

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/devel/lib/project_folder/executable_file",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "preLaunchTask": "prerun",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "targetArchitecture": "x64",
            "avoidWindowsConsoleRedirection": true,
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

---

*******************************************************   **tasks.json**   **************************************************

```
    {
        // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
        // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
        "version": "2.0.0",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "label": "prerun",
                "type": "shell",
                "command": "source ./devel/setup.bash && export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311/ "
            },
            {
                "label": "build",
                "type": "shell",
                "command": "catkin config --extend /opt/ros/kinetic && catkin build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = Debug -j8",
                "group": {
                    "kind": "build",
                    "isDefault": true
                },
                "problemMatcher": []
            },
            {
                "label": "clean",
                "type": "shell",
                "command": "catkin clean --yes"
            },
            {
                "label": "release",
                "type": "shell",
                "command": "sudo checkinstall --install=no catkin build -j4 --cmake--args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"
            }
        ]

}
```

---

Originally posted by [sai krishna](https://answers.ros.org/users/29950/sai-krishna/) with karma: 111 on 2019-02-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [onlytailei](https://answers.ros.org/users/25561/onlytailei/) on 2019-12-20**:
Then I guess when can not use other atributes in ROSLAUNCH like param right?

**Comment by [Diogo42](https://answers.ros.org/users/40037/diogo42/) on 2020-11-30**:
Is the best answer, i make one gist based in your answer :
https://gist.github.com/diogon01/6e5097607a2b0a33730981f8bfadde91

**Comment by [sai krishna](https://answers.ros.org/users/29950/sai-krishna/) on 2021-09-17**:
Hope it worked :)